# 別シートへのコピー＆ペーストがうまくできません

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

会社名を「（東京都）元ダミーデータ」のA1:A5の列から、「現在実行した結果出力されるシート」へのB1:B10と、B12:B22まで出力したいです。

このコードを実行しても、セルに値が出力されません

```
function COMPANY() {
  function COMPANY() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //スプレッドシートをGASで使う宣言
  for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
  let  v = i+11;
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('（東京都）元ダミーデータ'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A' + i).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'（東京都）元ダミーデータ\'!A' + i).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('現在実行した結果出力されるシート'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B' + v).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'（東京都）元ダミーデータ\'!A' + i).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  
  //会社名をB1:B10と、B12:B22まで出力
   } 
}
```

[image: 企業名ダミーデータ]

[image: 完成した後のイメージ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

変数宣言では小文字 `v`、エラーが出ているコードでは大文字 `V` になってます。

Comment: ありがとうございます、そこと他のコードも修正してみたのですが、セルにコピーされませんでした

Comment: 「エラーが出る」という質問だったと思うのですが、そのエラーがこの回答で解決したのならこの質問は解決済みにして別の質問を立てるべきかと思います。質問内容が変えられてしまうと回答が意味不明になってしまいます。

Comment: 度々申し訳ございません。
解決済みとするためには、どのような操作を行う必要がありますか？

Comment: おおっしゃられている通りだと思いますので、この質問そのものは解決済みとして、別の質問を立ててみます